# PHP read word for word from file

Tags: php, file, loops

Why are this code not working if i comment out the if statement it prints the file.

```
<?php

$f = fopen("test.txt", "r");

// Read line by line until end of file
while(!feof($f)) { 
    $arrays = explode("\n",fgets($f));
    foreach($arrays as $words){
        if($words == "andersmarkc"){
            echo $words;
        }
    }
}

fclose($f);

?>
```

Comment: what it's not working, what it's the output. Also `\n` it's a break line

Comment: Function fgets() gets a line from file, then if you want words you have to explode this line by the spaces which presumably are between the words, so the line shoud be: $arrays = explode(" ",fgets($f));

Comment: @Picard Thanks worked like a charm